# Parsing a string of the form "key1=value1;key2=value2;" into a Hash

Tags: ruby, parsing

I need to parse the following input string into a hash table with the following format:

Input:

```
'1001=23;1001B=5;1002=0;1003=5;'
```

Output:

```
=> {'1001'=>23,'1001B'=>5,'1002'=>0,'1003'=>5}
```

My solution:

```
def parser input
  output = {}
  input.split(';').map {|ar| ar.split('=')}.each {|id, c| output[id]=c.to_i}
  output
end
parser '1001=23;1001B=5;1002=0;1003=5;'
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make it a single expression by taking advantage of [`Hash[[key, value], …]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) (available since Ruby 1.9).

The function name could probably be improved.

When using `String#split`, I consider it good practice to limit the number of splits whenever a limit may be applicable.  Here, you wouldn't be able to tolerate a second `=` sign within each `key=value` string, so you should use `pair.split('=', 2)`.

```
def to_hash(str)
  Hash[
    str.split(';').map do |pair|
      k, v = pair.split('=', 2)
      [k, v.to_i]
    end
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a method or a classmethod? since it's not using anything of the instance, it probably should be a classmethod. I'd write:

```
def self.parser(strval)
  strval.split(';').map do |pair|
    key, value = pair.split('=')
    [key, value.to_i]
  end.to_h
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify what you have by using `each` rather than `map` and performing all operations in one block:

```
def parser input
    output = {}
    input.split(';')
         .each do |s|
            k,v = s.split('=')
            output[k] = v.to_i
          end
    output
 end
```

Further simplification is possible by using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def parser input
  input.split(';')
       .each_with_object({}) do |s,output|
          k,v = s.split('=')
          output[k]=v.to_i
        end
 end
```

Here's another way:

```
def parser input
  input.split(/=|;/).each_slice(2)
                    .with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k]=v.to_i }
end
```